# Does AWS IoT SDK enable us to use HTTP protocol?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot

This link (https://aws.amazon.com/iot-core/features/) says that: "The AWS IoT Device SDK enables your devices to connect, authenticate, and exchange messages with AWS IoT Core using the **MQTT, HTTP, or WebSockets protocols**."

This link (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-sdks.html) says that: "These SDKs help you connect your IoT devices to AWS IoT using the **MQTT and WSS protocols**."

This link (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/protocols.html) says that, for HTTPS: "**No SDK support**, but you can use language-specific methods to make HTTPS requests"

I am confused about whether the SDK supports HTTPS as mentioned in link1; or does it not support as mention in link 2 and link 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AWS IoT SDK provides support for HTTPS using the AWS IoT Data Plane API. e.g.

- Javascript SDK - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/goto/AWSJavaScriptSDK/iot-data-2015-05-28/Publish
- C++ - https://sdk.amazonaws.com/cpp/api/LATEST/class_aws_1_1_io_t_data_plane_1_1_io_t_data_plane_client.html#ad35ec5e43dc902c49379104387ef9b5b
- Python - https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iot-data.html#IoTDataPlane.Client.publish

However, devices and clients using HTTPS can only publish messages. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/protocols.html